# How do you make a gridview only populate after information is entered?

Tags: gridview, webforms

I am sure this is incredibly simple but I have a gridview, tableadapter, objectdatasource, and a textbox.

When I run the page I get:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: permanent

This is because my query has a parameter that it is looking for from the textbox.  If I manually enter in data for the textbox's text value and load the page, the query runs fine.

How do I make it so the query only runs after I put data into my textbox?  I don't want the query to run until someone put something in to search for.  I looked at all the properties and didn't see anything obvious.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing any significant details about your setup, I would say you need to use some sort of event and an if statement. I would create a button which checks that something exists in the textbox and then processes the query.  I am assuming you are using ASP.NET. You can use TextBox.Text.Length to check the length of the text in the TextBox.

Something like this:

```
private void bSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(tbSearchBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
          doQuery(tbSearchBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Of course, if your particular use calls for it, you can always put it in a text changed event so it does a query for each new character entered.